# Handstand Pushup Progression

Tags: exercise, muscle, strength, calisthenics

I am doing handstand pushups. What is a good way to increase progression of handstand pushups without using a weight vest? I am open to suggestions using a wall, or not against a wall. Thanks,

[image]

Comment: What specifically do you want to progress? Without adding weight you're limited to reps and speed. Either increase reps, decrease rep speed, or try 21s (or any variation of partial reps)?

Comment: hi @DaveNewton I want to increase strength

Comment: What rep range are you at right now? What do you mean by increase strength, increasing reps or increase the weight you are able to do handstand pushups with, lower reps, etc? What is your end goal, strength is too broad of a term.

Comment: So your goal is to increase the weight you are able to do reps at, without a weight vest?

Comment: yeah @EricWarburton. some gymnast I spoke to few years ago , says its possible, but I doubt there is a magical solution at this point

Comment: Our bodies are designed to adapt to the training stimulus that we provide. It will provide not only muscular adaptations in the form of more muscle mass, but it will provide neuromuscular adaptations that allow our muscles to be more efficient via new blood vessels and more efficient ways to communicate with the muscles under load. So obviously training with more weight with something like a weight vest is the best way to increase the weight you are able to push. You can also increase weight by increasing volume, but it won't be as efficient.

Comment: You are doing 10x3, so you can increase by doing 10x4, or if your balance starts to fall off, perform your last set on a wall and go until failure. The only way you will be able to do more is by loading more. Perhaps do some shoulder press if you have access to weights and progressively overload with those.

Comment: If that's you in the picture doing weighted free-standing handstand pushups on parallel bars, maybe you should be telling us how to get stronger.

Comment: hi @michael thats not me

Comment: @mattsmith5 Ironically you doing 10x3 probably puts you as the best at handstand pushups out of anyone currently active on this site. I PRd last week at 10, and I'm not sure if anyone else even does calisthenics here.

Comment: hi @EricWarburton excuse me, I meant to say 5x3 , you are still the top recordholder on this messageboard  : )

Comment: @EricWarburton Depends if you are talking with a wall or without. With a wall I do way more than 10, without a wall it's harder because as fatigue sets in, keeping balance becomes harder ;) My profile has a summary of the things I do, I thought I was the only one doing caslithenics here! Nice to meet you :)

Comment: @MJB lets move this into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/324/the-locker-room)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount of info is very minimal so this is all I can give you: the only conclusion I make based on this picture is that you mainly need to work on mobility and form. It seems like you already have the strength. I think working on form will help you get more reps or more added weight.

The things that I would work on is;

- **Shoulder mobility**, you want to be 1 straight line when you stand on your hands.
- **Core and glute engagement**, again to do with being straight and having full control over your handstand. It seems like your core and glutes are not engaged fully, which makes your handstand slightly sloppy. This also has to do with the previous point.

You can see an example in the picture below. You want your hands, shoulders, hips, knees and ankles to be in a straight line to have full control over your handstand. If for example your hips aren't in line with your hands, your knees and feet also won't be.

[image]

Having full control over your handstand will help tremendously towards doing more HPU reps.

If for what ever reason you really just want to increase power, simply doing HPUs against a wall will help. This eliminates the balance part out of the movement, so you can fully focus on getting the reps in. After you have comfortably increased reps against a wall, you'll notice that you can also do more reps without a wall.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thats not me in the picture, but thanks for the info : )

Comment: @mattsmith5 Ah I see. Well my comment still applies if your form isn't great, but there is no way for me to judge your form ;). Let me know if there is anything more specific you want to know!

Answer (score -3):

The best thing about standing exercises first is to strengthen the abdominal muscles and then focus and create contraction on those muscles when doing standing exercises. Reverse movements of a different world and having mental focus is the most important thing

The photo you took shows that you left the pelvis and the bottom of the spine. Concentrate on standing on the ball and take it (like Dandasana or Virabadrasana) and after learning this, use it in reverse movements. namaste

Comment: I don't understand this answer, what is Dandasana or Virabadrasana?

Comment: These are yoga poses that help you strengthen Abdominal muscles (Rectus Abdominis muscles) .
These two poses hold you in handstand and don not make your body to be in shape of a banana